# Problem with fetching and displaying API header error

Tags: javascript

```
// const fs = require("node:fs");
// const myKey = fs.readFileSync("MyKey.txt", "utf8").trim();

const myKey = '...';



const getTag = () => {
  let originalTag = document.getElementById("tag").value;

  if (originalTag[0] === '#') {
    return originalTag.slice(1);
  }
  return originalTag;
}

function visualiseName() {
  document.getElementById("playerInfo").innerText = searchAPI(getTag());;

  
}

let searchAPI = (tag) => {
  const baseUrl = "https://api.clashroyale.com/v1";
  const endpoint = `/players/%23${getTag()}`;

  const url = baseUrl + endpoint;

  

  const requestOptions = {
    method: "GET",
    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${myKey}` }
  };

  fetch(url, requestOptions)
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.status === response.ok) {
        return response.json();
      } else {
        console.error("Request failed with status code: ", response.status);
      }
    })
    .then((data) => {
      if (data) {
        return data;
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error making the request: ", error);
    });
}
```

1. Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://api.clashroyale.com/v1/players/%2389GU9VUQJ. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 400.
2. This is the error we get. How can we fix this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are calling the API from a browser. This will not work, since CORS will be enforced and there doesn't seem to be any CORS headers in the response of the API.
The reason why they don't include any CORS headers is probably to discourage/disallow calls from a client environment (e.g. browser), because that would expose your API key, which is supposed to be private.

You need to move your code to a server environment, for example NodeJS.